# Why does the Star Trek theme appear in the Zelda Symphony?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, video-games, music, the-legend-of-zelda

In ["Ballad of the Wind Fish - Legend of Zelda Symphony of the Goddesses"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6T5n8zSbX0&feature=youtu.be&t=3m47s) at 3:47 we randomly hear the [main theme from *Star Trek*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EWSp5ijOOfk) for just a short moment. Why? Why is there a *Star Trek* reference in the Zelda symphony? Has anyone involved in the Zelda Symphony commented on this decision or the reasons behind it?

Comment: I agree --- those are the same 4 notes, with roughly the same spacing, that appear at the beginning of Alexander Courage's theme for *TOS*.  But it's just those 4 notes, so it could be completely coincidental.

Comment: Ha, see also: http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/3118/129

Comment: This was cross posted to multiple SE's.  It should probably be closed here since it was asked first on "Music Fans".

Comment: @ChrisSunami while coss posting is discouraged, it's not prohibited. I only asked here on SFF because I'm more likely to get an answer from avid, knowledgeable fans here, whereas MusicFans.SE tends to be more casual fans. The answer on MusicFans.SE only found the evidence I was looking for once I'd asked on SFF. I only hesitate to delete the one on MusicFans.SE because I don't want BCdotWEB to loose any rep. But now I know for next time. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Apparently this is an Easter egg.

> [@ChadSeiter](https://twitter.com/ChadSeiter) are the four Star Trek notes at 3:47 in Ballad of the Wind Fish (https://t.co/gtANbSIIhj) an Easter egg?— Jack B Nimble [March 7, 2016](https://twitter.com/jonkroupa/status/706891097016918016)

> HAHA yes! Good catch - yes it was exactly that, an easter egg to my Star Trek game score. You are the first person to notice!— Chad Seiter (@ChadSeiter) [March 7, 2016](https://twitter.com/ChadSeiter/status/706902565867298816)

According to the [show info](http://www.san-francisco-theater.com/theaters/davies-symphony-hall/the-legend-of-zelda-symphony-of-the-goddesses.php):

> "The Legend of Zelda: Symphony of the Goddesses" is the first ever video game themed concert to feature a complete 4-movement symphony, **arranged by Zelda Symphony music director Chad Seiter (Star Trek, LOST and Fringe)**, showcasing the enduring and ever-adored work of Nintendo composer and sound director Koji Kondo and his dedicated music team.

Comment: picking at nit's here - if it is the first four notes of the Alexander Courage theme it isn't an easter egg to "**my** Star Trek game score". It is an easter egg to a score from 50 years ago. Credit where credit is due Chad

Comment: Did you just contact Chad Seiter directly and ask him?! That's so cool! Also, if you're the first person to bring it up to him, then that technically makes _me_ the first person to notice it! :)